# vehicle finance calculation php

Tags: php, formula, calculator, finance

I am trying to build a vehicle finance calculator, i would like to improve the code by displaying each month principle payment and each months interest, i have the following code

```
$interest = 10 /100/12;//10 is the interest rate
$months = 60; //60 months term
$loan = 12000;// total loan amount

$monthly_payment = $loan * $interest / (1-(pow((1+$interest),-$months)));
$total_payable = $monthly_payment * $months;
$total_interest = ($total_payable - $loan);

echo "Monthly Payment = " . $monthly_payment. '<br>';
echo "Total Payable = " . $total_payable . '<br>';
echo "Total Interest = " . $total_interest . '<br>';
echo "Monthly Interest = " . ($total_interest / $months) . '<br>';
```

to do what i want i need to use the formula on this page
http://www.ifsautoloans.com/car-loan-interest/

this is the formula

$100 [$100 = 10%/12 months * $12,000). Consequently, with the first payment, you will pay down your principal by $154.96 [$154.96 = $254.96 – $100].

i just don't understand it, thank you for any help

what i want to do is the same as this link

http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/carloancalculator.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm giving you quick `PHP` with a form and output table for monthly view without any styling. The variables are self-explanatory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Loan Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form-wrapper">
        <h2>Enter your car loan Details...</h2>
        <form id="calculate-loan" method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="currency">Currency:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="currency" name="currency">
                                <option>$</option>
                                <option>&#8377;</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="vehicle_value">Vehicle Value:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="vehicle_value" name="vehicle_value"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="interest_rate">Interest Rate:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="interest_rate" name="interest_rate"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="months">Months:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" step="1" id="months" name="months"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ?>
    <div id="loan-details">
        <h2>Vehicle Loan Repayments By Month</h2>
        <?php
            $balance = (float) $_POST['vehicle_value'];
            $monthly_payment = (($_POST['interest_rate'] /(100 * 12)) * $_POST['vehicle_value']) / (1 - pow(1 + $_POST['interest_rate'] / 1200,  (-$_POST['months'])));
        ?>
        <p>
            Loan Payments: <?php echo $_POST['currency'].number_format($monthly_payment * $_POST['months'], 2); ?><br />
            Monthly Payment: <?php echo $_POST['currency'].number_format($monthly_payment, 2); ?><br />
            Total Interest: <?php echo $_POST['currency'].number_format($monthly_payment * $_POST['months'] - $balance, 2); ?>
        </p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                    <th>Principal</th>
                    <th>Interest</th>
                    <th>Payment</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                for($month = 0; $month < (int)$_POST['months']; $month++) {
                    $interest = $balance * $_POST['interest_rate'] / 1200;
                    $principal = $monthly_payment - $interest;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $month + 1 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['currency']. number_format($balance, 2) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['currency']. number_format($principal, 2) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['currency']. number_format($interest, 2) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['currency']. number_format($monthly_payment, 2) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $balance -= $principal;
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much i was nearly there but your way is much better thanks again

Comment: rmalviya@you there... I Need  this in Indian currency convertor.. And want include monthly EmI option also.. can you please update this

Comment: @SanjayYadav Although I didn't understand your question, if you want to display the Indian rupees then, just select second option in currency select, Math doesn't depend on currency.

Comment: rmalviya@yes I got it .. my question is that i want  calculate  loan with existing Emi  also please see this url  https://www.paisabazaar.com/loan-eligibility-calculator/

Comment: Ramalvivya.@ you there?

Comment: @SanjayYadav You can't ask for complete solution of a programming problem, without trying by yourself on [so]. Try by yourself, take help from this question or other online resources and ask a new question by providing the info what you've tried if you can't figure it out correctly.

Comment: Rmalviya@please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126631/loan-eligibility-calculator.. I have no Idea how to create this..

Comment: ramalviya can you help me regarding  loan Eligibility calculator